# Color selecting from a layer in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, selections, actions

If I create a new layer and draw into it with a single color, then change my foreground color, is there any way I can select the color I painted into the layer as my foreground color again, without using the dropper?

I'm trying to work it into an action and I want to select the color from the layer with no manual effort so the action runs smoothly.

The action's purpose is to let me take a raster shape that I've drawn on a layer and transform it into a Fill Layer shape with the same color as the original layer. The closest I've got is to create an action that works providing I manually select the color with the eyedropper before I run it, but it would be good to exclude that manual step.

Thanks.

**Edit for clarification**
So on this image, I would want to turn Layer 3 (the teal layer) into a 'Base Layer' while preserving its shape and color, without having to manually set the color in any way.

[image]

Comment: What you're asking is not possible but I, or someone else, may be able to offer you another solution but first I need to understand the purpose and goal. Come into [Inkspot, our chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) and I can try to help you.

Comment: I don't have sufficient 'reputation' to speak there...

Comment: Go read and upvote on some answers and questions and you'll get rep. Otherwise try to explain better on here. I have a few ideas in mind but without knowing the ultimate goal am not sure if any work for you.

Comment: I really can't think of a way to explain it concisely. The actions are for colouring within line work. We have one which lets us make a selection with the magic wand and then make a fill layer from it. At the point of creation we select the colour we want. The fill layer is labelled 'Base Layer' which is then used as the basis for several other actions we use. All good. Sometimes however we want to paint in the selection by hand rather than by using the magic wand. In those cases we still need to transform the painted layer into a 'Base Layer' for use in the other actions...more to come...

Comment: ...we can ctrl click the layer to make a selection and then make a fill layer from it, but in an action that will always change it to the colour originally selected when the action was recorded. We could pre-select the foreground colour and then apply a fill from foreground colour after the fill layer, but that requires manually selecting the colour.

The problem is that to set any colour for use you have to manually select it at some point....

Comment: ...It's really important that it's a fill layer as you can change the colour of the layer by double clicking the layer, which is something designers often have to do with our assets.

Comment: But "Fill Layer" isn't a specific term. Can you describe this layer at least?A screenshot which includes both the canvas and your layer panel would go a long way. Sounds like by fill layer you mean Solid Color Adjustment Layer but I'm not positive

Comment: We could also put in a modal control to let us select the colour we want at the point of running the action, but by that point it's already reverted in the colour palette to the colour selected when the action was recorded so again it's manually selecting the colour from the foreground colour, which we need to have pre-selected.

Comment: Ah okay. I've added a screenshot to the OG question. :)

Comment: @Ian as I wrote in my answer, if you select the colors from the swatches palette while recording the action, after when the action is played you don't need to make any *manual procedure*. Actually you can duplicate the same "selecting color" command in the action.

Comment: @Danielillo As I understand it I'd have to set the colours I wanted on the colour palette before I ran the action?

Comment: Just if you need "special" colors that doesn't exist in the default color swatches palette

Comment: We don't use many preset swatches, so we would need to set the swatches each time. That's what I meant before, it would take us just as much time to set the swatches up before we ran the action as it would to pick the colour with the eye dropper prior to using it.

Comment: I apologise if it appears I'm being picky here. It's just I work for a large organisation and these actions are to replace some others that are already pretty quick and refined. If the new actions don't out perform the new ones in efficiency they won't get used :)

Comment: Whew! Took a bit of tinkering but I think Ive got a working solution for you! I'll document it and maybe even do a video of it tonight or Saturday for you.

Comment: What if you switch the foreground & background colors as part of the action & use the background color to store the color in between steps? That way you can keep at least one extra color up your sleeve during the action at any given time

Comment: Hi Ryan, did you get chance to document that process? I see you had you comment flagged??!

Answer (score 1):

- Copy the single color hex number used in the drawing
- To recover it as a foreground color, add this command to the action:

  - Click the foreground color
  - Paste

**Add after the comments:**

The previous answer only works by obtaining the color once, in this way the copied hexadecimal number is saved in the clipboard.

By making several layers at the same time using different colors, the only possibility of obtaining the color of the first layer is using colors from the **Swatches Panel**. Selecting a color from the **Swatches Panel** can be inserted as an action command.

**Second add:**

While recording the action, instead of selecting the colors from the tool panel, do it from the **Swatches Panel**. The action is recorded with this used swatch and this command can be duplicated and place it everywhere in the action and will always be the same color.

[image]

Comment: Thanks again Danielillo, but I'm uncertain how I'd copy the single hex number? It's not the only colour in the drawing, just the only colour in that layer.

Comment: I suppose at some point you have selected that color, when you open the foreground color to get it, the hexadecimal number is active, choose the color and copy.

Comment: Say I make 5 layers and each one has a different colour, painted with a brush. Once I've drawn the 5th layer my foreground colour will be a different one to the 1st layer.

Action process:

Set Selection (using ctrl click on the layer in the layer panel)
Make Fill Layer
Fill (using foregorund colour)
Select backward layer
Delete layer

I want to be able to select the 1st layer in may stack and have the action set the foreground colour to be the same as the single colour in that layer, without me having to manually select it with the eyedropper; and then use that in the Fill step.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Ah thanks again Danielillo. I don't think it's possible to do what I'm wanting. It still requires a manual selection of the colour I want in order to make the swatch. It saves time in the action, but defers the selection of the colour elsewhere. But I do appreciate the time spent trying to solve this for me, and I've learnt a few things that may help with future actions!